# CXF RS proxy service example

Tags: cxf, jax-rs, apache-camel, cxfrs

I need to do create proxy service for rest full services. I am aware about how to create proxy services, i need help for creating some simple proxy services in cxf-rs/jaxrs services. If anyone can provide any examples..

Comment: did you get any solution ? if yes please post it here

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the request and response, you can just setup a simple http proxy with camel just like this.

```
from("jetty://localhost:8000/proxy/").to("http://service/context/?bridgeEndpoint=true")
```

Comment: i am trying to implement the load balancer in fuse. but i am confused after reading all the docs. if i can get some consolidated doc that can help me..